# Creating a custom Admin panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I'm building a Wordpress Plugin and it has two tables and some data.
Right now, for displaying and changing the data, I'm using the wpdb function and manually creating the user interface (mimicking the Default one).

However, I see that other plugins have a more consistent style with their tables and the same features (like the bulk button). I'm getting suspicious about Wordpress Taxonomies. I read, but so far, taxonomies seems to be related to posts in a way or the other.

My data doesn't relate to posts, it's completely independent. Can I still use Wordpress Taxonomies? Can the taxonomy help me build a consistent interface?

Comment: If the data has nothing to do with posts then why would you want to use taxonomies? Taxonomies are used to create relationships between posts(or custom types), ie. groupings of posts that fall under specific terms. Personally i don't think WP Taxonomies will be much use to you here.

Comment: .. if you're displaying custom data it makes sense you'd need to handle the result filtering yourself using functions that imitate the WP filters.

Comment: @Omar Abid - Can you explain your use-case. It's very hard for us to help you in abstract. Also, I think the title of your question does not accurately reflect your actual question. Can you consider re-titling your question?

Comment: @t31os - You know taxonomy can be used for anything including non-posts. That's why `wp_term_relationships` has an `object_id` field instead of a `post_id` field. Think users, comments, meta, even taxonomy terms themselves. So yes I think someone could use a taxonomy for their own custom tables. OTOH, I'm suspicious whenever someone creates a new table. From what I've seen 9 times out of 10 time they could have used a built-in table with less hassle.

Comment: @Mike, I think we are getting close. I just wanted to know if I give Wordpress the structure of my data (through taxonomy or anything else) can it produce the table automagically?

Comment: @Mike - What happens when a post holds the same object ID as a record in the custom table(since they're seperate tables assigning they're own IDs), surely that's going to cause some confusion with the internal taxonomies, no?

Comment: @Omar Adid - Your questions are unclear. When you ask about a table, do you mean SQL table or HTML table? And where do you want to produce it, in your database or in your browser when you are in the admin console?

Comment: @t31os - That's what I assumed initially. Then it hit me: taxonomy is what defines the source of the data. For example, if you have a taxonomy `'employee-role'` then your usages for `object_id` would be limited to `user_id`, if you have a taxonomy `'comment-type'` then `object_id` would relate to `comment_ID`, and so on. So term relationships don't exist independently, they must mate with a taxonomy to have meaning. Of course your code would need to guarantee those business rules, but the structure does work conceptually. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @Mike - Certainly does.. :) However i'm still not convinced it would work well, i simply can't see how you could leverage enough of the existing API to make it worth it. The term functions aren't necessarily going to work for something of a non-post type nature, and if you're going to be writing your own functions for insertion/updates/deletions you might aswell at that point be using your own table(or none). I think the bigger question here though is, what is the data? Would it really be appropriate/worth the usage of taxonomies in this instance..

Comment: @t31os: Fair point about the functions, but I personally think new tables should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. I also think the taxonomy system provides the raw materials to store that data so why not reuse it rather than build yet more tables? I've found many cases where WordPress simply doesn't (yet) have the API to support existing MySQL structures, not just with taxonomy. But I do agree that it's always a question of _"is it appropriate"_ for this or any other architecture question. BTW I started a thread on wp-hackers to get their feedback on this question; maybe I'm offbase?

Comment: @Mike - **RE: Email to list:** I think you misunderstood what i was trying to get at so i'll try to clarify.... Even if you use the taxonomy tables in WP, i don't think you'll be able to leverage alot of the taxonomy functionality from WordPress(ie. term update/fetching functions) because they're written with expectations on the data coming in or being fetched(ie. posts). If you're going to be writing your own SQL queries via WPDB then at that point you have to ask yourself what's easier, update/deletes/inserts on 1 custom table or update/delete/insert joins across the 3 taxonomy tables?

Comment: .. further, if you're performing queries to the taxonomy tables, you best make damn sure the queries are right, else you'll run the risk of messing up your WP terms and taxonomies. The risk factor is higher when you're writing to and updating existing tables with custom writen queries, which is a problem that would to be totally illeviated if your custom data was in the form of a custom post type(because you'd then be able to leverage the existing taxonomy/term functions).

Comment: @t31os - Points taken but I don't think I previously misunderstood; at least I didn't see your points differently with your clarification other than your elaboration. Point taken about making sure queries are right, but is it really that hard? You only need to make sure `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` are correct, but those are less common. Incorrect `SELECT`s can always be fixed. There are examples in core for how to do it right, and once you've added taxonomy to users, for example, it's done for all future use.  RE:Email to list, did you see Otto's response?

Comment: @t31os - You said *"is it easier to update/deletes/inserts on one custom table"* and you have a point there, but only some. Usually you don't have to update all three, just one, i.e. the `wp_term_relationships` table. With taxonomy you get admin functionality for maintaining terms for free and for your own tables you have to write the admin yourself. I'd much rather write 3 SQL `INSERT` statements then build an admin add/edit/delete module. But I do agree that in selected use-cases it's better to have custom tables. But I think there are fewer cases justified than custom tables I've seen.

Comment: @t31os - Lastly, if you add custom tables they are yours and yours alone. If they are for your site then okay. But if they are for a plugin or theme then you have added tables to my database that only your plugin or theme supports and I really don't want those kind of tables in my database. If I add a plugin and it installs it's own tables I think very long and hard about if I really want to depend on it because having tons of tables just create too much clutter to manage IMO. I'm far prefer to have a few very well know tables than a ton of obscure tables. But then that could just be me.

Comment: @Mike - Yes i saw Otto's response, he pretty much nailed all of my concerns, and that's all they are really.. concerns. I'd not be so worried i guess if there were some clear examples available for us(users)/anyone to refer to, i'm just worried you've diving into in a relatively unexplored realm.

Comment: @t31os - Fair points all.

Comment: @Mike. What I meant is: I have a SQL Table in the Wordpress DataBase, I want to display the data to the user in a HTML table (just like Wordpress does with posts, comments, users). Can this be done automatically by Wordpress by some API inside it? (instead of me having to design the whole thing myself and also do the queries).

Comment: @Omad Abid - Not really. There are functions you can use but you'll still write lots of code. Can you update your question and actually describe your use case? It's very hard to visual how to help you when we are discussing things in the abstract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check [**this**](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/) out, I believe this might be what you're looking for. it helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the link. That's actually what I have done. I'm just wandering if taxonomies can do it automatically for you.

Comment: That's a great link, but i'd note one thing, there's no need to write any HTML for the admin icons, you can call them like this.. `<?php screen_icon('themes') ?>` (if you wanted the themes icon).